# sqlite join statement with 3 tables and filters

Tags: android, sql, join, filter

hi i have a little bit confusion about this SQL Query in Android with SQlite

i have 3 simple tables
table category

```
   |_id|name| 
   |1  |cat1
   |2  |cat2
   |3  |cat3
   |4  |cat4
```

table list

```
   |_id|name| 
   |1  |list1
   |2  |list2
   |3  |list3
   |4  |list4
```

and i have other table which contains the id s for previous tables

```
|_id|category|list   |name
| 1 |2       |1      |item1
| 2 |1       |2      |item2
| 3 |2       |3      |item3
| 4 |2       |1      |item4
```

i want to left join the cat table so 
that is always shown as 
cat1 (count 10)
cat2 (count 2)
cat3 (count 3)
cat4 (count 4)

when i filter with where list = 1 then the category doesn show the null columns

any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a subquery:

```
SELECT category.name as cat, B.catcount as catcount
FROM category LEFT JOIN (SELECT table3.category, count(*) AS catcount
FROM table3
WHERE table3.list=1
GROUP BY table3.category) as B ON category.[_id] = B.category;
```

Should give an output like:

```
|cat  |catcount|
|cat1 |    null|
|cat2 |       2|
|cat3 |    null|
|cat4 |    null|
```

Comment: yeah it's perfect i understand everything but can you explain the sum() function is for aggregation so what does it do since theres nothing added to the count thanks

Comment: It was there because in my first approach that `sum()` was needed, and I changed it before posting but forgot to fix that part. Nevertheless it was harmless.